# Automatically increment AssemblyFileVersion on build?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'd like to automatically update the AssemblyFileVersion on each build, though not the AssemblyVersion.

Is there any easy way that don't require every developer to install the MSBuild community tasks ?

(I'd basically like AssemblyVersion("1.0.*") but for the AssemblyFileVersion )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the MSBuild community tasks in your version control system, there's no need to install it.

Comment: +1: I think this is a valid answer because the default rule set is unbelievably limited. Every developer needs the community tasks. Either that or your own custom tasks - there are too many things MSBuild can't do out-of-the-box.

Comment: How do you actually use it? It doesn't seem to work, still complains `CSC : warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '2.0.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format`

Answer (score 1):

I use this tool:

http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes, but that's fundamentally a build server.  The tool I pointed to, integrates with Visual Studio IDE.  After all, sometimes a build server is overkill.

Comment: +1 This tool is awesome! Haven't tried the VS2010 beta yet but the VS2008 one works perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work out of the box with MSBuild? Or am I doing something wrong? Works in VS2008 fine.